# HTML Canvas doesn't diplay rectangle if written to off screen canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have tried to create an HTML page with a full screen canvas and I can draw to this fine. If I create a second "off screen" canvas to draw on and display on the main canvas I do not see anything.

My code is:

```js
var canvas;
var canvas_ctx;
var off_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var off_canvas_ctx;

init();
drawTree();

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('treeCanvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    canvas_ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);
    resizeCanvas();
  }
  off_canvas.width = 5000;
  off_canvas.height = 5000;
  off_canvas_ctx = off_canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  var cWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var cHeight = window.innerHeight - 3;
  var imgData = canvas_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
  // Resize original canvas
  canvas.width = cWidth;
  canvas.height = cHeight;
  // Copy back to resized canvas
  canvas_ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}

function drawTree() {
  canvas_ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  canvas_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
  off_canvas_ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  off_canvas_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
  resizeCanvas();
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <canvas id="treeCanvas" width="200" height="100">
    Your browser does not support the canvas element.
  </canvas>
</div>
```

My "drawTree()" function currently draws the same thing to both canvas contexts and then calls "resizeCanvas()" in order to update the display.

If I use the line

`var imgData = canvas_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);`

in "resizeCanvas()", the rectangle displays but if I try to use the image data from the off screen canvas with the line

`var imgData = off_canvas_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);`

then nothing is displayed. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, in the "init()" function i was calling "resizeCanvas()" before i had got the context to the second canvas, this seemed to mess it up for the rest of the session.

```
    canvas_ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    off_canvas.width = 5000;
    off_canvas.height = 5000;
    off_canvas_ctx = off_canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Moving the block up appears to have fixed the problem.